# Connecting MySQL DB to Apple iWork Numbers?

Tags: iwork, numbers, mysql

I'd like to visualize some data from a MySQL database using a Mac, but it hasn't been easy finding a solution to this. I understand Excel has DB connectivity, but currently I only have Apple Numbers.

Is it possible to connect my data source to Numbers so I can start making some charts?

Thanks for the suggestions and information; I'm exploring using OOO Base and Calc instead

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to make Numbers get data from a database. (It's more of a consumer tool.) https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1827581

A workaround: you can use Excel to grab the data, and import the XLS file to Numbers for prettier chart-making.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one-time thing, you can export your data into a .csv file, and then open it with Numbers. Use a query similar to this to export the data:

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty
FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do this, is opening the table in phpMySQL, then simply copy'n'paste the data into Numbers. It's not automatic, but works like a charm if don't mind the added step and/or you don't have to do it with many different tables.

My workflow:

1. Open phpMySQL in the view that I want (use a bookmark for that)
2. Copy the results table
3. Paste in Numbers matching style (cmd+shift+opt+V)

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use Open Office Base which runs on Mac, Windows and Linux. This does support mysql, and this is what I use to store data and retrieve data from my MySql server.